# weblogic 10.3.2 loses configuration after restart

Tags: configuration, console, weblogic

I am trying to create a new mail session in the weblogic console. I am acquiring the lock and 
activating the changes to make it visible in the session. I am also able to use it in the 
current session. But the problem is that mail session change is lost when I restart my 
server. I have to reconfigure the mail session to use it again. 
The weblogic server is running in production mode.
Please help.

Thanks & Regards,
Sujeet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was happening because of a custom script which was overwriting the changes to config.xml upon restart.

Answer (score 0):

> In order to make configuration changes through the WLS console, obtain a lock on the editable collection of Configuration MBeans for all servers in the domain. The lock is obtained by clicking the **Lock & Edit** button.
>
> After performing configuration changes you click the **Save** or the **Finish** button. However the changes do not take effect immediately. You have to click the **Activate Changes** button in the Change Center so that the configuration changes are distributed to each of the servers in the domain. Some changes require a server restart in order to take effect.

The configuration changes are saved in the **config.xml** file which is located in the path: your_domain_name\config.

You should see a mail-session element in the config.xml:

```
<mail-session>
    <name>MailSession-0</name>
</mail-session>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply Tolis. I am doing exactly the same. I can see that the changes are not written to the config.xml file.

Comment: Do you obtain the lock on the editable collection of Configuration MBeans for all servers in the domain by clicking the **Lock & Edit** in the WLS console?

Comment: Yes Tolis. Lock was obtained.

Comment: It was happening because of a custom script which was overwriting the changes to config.xml upon restart.